# cargar un objeto con tabla de la base de datos ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Hola buen día estoy creando un objeto de tipo software, al crearlo quisiera poder traerlo ya precargado con la información correspondiente de la base de datos

Tengo tablas software y mantenimiento al ser una Relacion Muchos - Muchos agregue una tabla intermedia Mantenimiento software

estoy en el controlador y vista de mantenimiento en la sección edit

y necesito traer los datos de la tabla intermedia que sirve de registro y basicamente decirle si id( mantenimiento) es igual a mantenimiento_id (mantenimientoSoftware) traeme los id de software_id(mantenimientosoftware)

hasta esta parte ya llegue con un selectList con EntitiFramework pero solo me trae los id y no puedo conseguir los nombres que corresponden a ese id ya que es de la tabla software y no logro acceder ah esa instancia
mi idea es traerme un objeto software lleno con todos los datos de la tabla software y hacer la comparacion de esos Ids con los de software y extraer esos nombes y mandarlos por un viewbag con selectList (Key,Value) y asi mostrarlos en un dropdownlist
la cuestión es que no logro generar el objeto de tipo software con los datos de la tabla (Eq_tblSoftware <- nombre de la tabla)

intente esto

```
Eq_tblSoftware Software = new db.Eq_tblSoftware();
```

intente eso pero me genera el objeto vacío

no se si alguien conocerá alguna forma o me pueda compartir algún articulo que de alguna idea

tambien intente con una consulta Linq que me genera lo deseado pero no me lo recibe el DropDawnList ya que me pide una estructura  Key, Value

Comment: Tienes que añadir mas información y mucho más código. Con el estado actual de la pregunta es imposible responderla. Por ejemplo ¿Que es `db.Eq_tblSoftware()`?

Comment: que tal Carlos Muñoz ya edite mi pregunta espero sea mas clara

Answer (score 0):

Al final hice la siguiente consulta con inerjoin y me resulto

```
                ViewBag.SoftwareId = new SelectList(db.Eq_tblSoftware.Join(db.Eq_tblMantenimientoSoftware,
                    s => s.id,
                    sa => sa.Eq_tblSoftware_id,
                     (s, sa) => new { Soft = s, MttoSoft = sa })
                  .Where(ssa => ssa.MttoSoft.Eq_tblMantenimiento_id == id)
                  .Select(ssa => ssa.Soft.Nombre));
                return View(eq_TblMantenimientos);
```